# Perlin Noise function returning same results for different inputs

Tags: java, noise, perlin-noise

I am using a perlin noise function to generate data for a game I am making, but for some reason it keeps returning the exact same results for different inputs. I spent like 4 hours trying to debug this on my FBM function and couldn't figure it out so I tried Ken Perlin's improved noise function and the same thing happens.

Does anyone know why this is? What is a good way to fix it? The only thing I have been able to do is add a decimal value like .6473 to the x and y coordinates, which helped, but introduced other problems such as the values repeating themselves inside the arrays.

Here is some test code. I am trying to create two different 2D arrays filled with noise values. The x and y inputs are coordinates from my game. On the lines with '********' after them, if I don't increase those values, both arrays will be filled with all zeros. In the example, the coordinates (0.0, -768.0) and (-1024.0, -768.0) return the exact same noise values. In my game, 9 different coordinates return the same values.

The Perlin Noise function I am using for this test is [here](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/)

```
public class TestPerlinMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int seed = 532434;

        //create first noise array
        double x = 0.0;    //x-coordinate
        double y = -768.0; //y-coordinate
        float z = 10.0f;

        double[][] test = new double[15][15];

        System.out.println("Noise Array 1: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < test[i].length; j++)
            {
                test[i][j] = ImprovedNoise.noise(x + (j * 64.0), y + (i * 64.0), 10.0);
                x += .314f;//************

                System.out.print(test[i][j] + " ");
            }
            y += .314f;//***********

        }
        System.out.println();

        //create 2nd noise array
        double x2 = -1024.0; //x coordinate
        double y2 = -768.0;  //y coordinate
        float z2 = 10.0f;    

        System.out.println();

        double[][] test2 = new double[15][15];

        System.out.println("Noise Array 2: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < test2.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < test2[i].length; j++)
            {
                test2[i][j] = ImprovedNoise.noise(x2 + (j * 64.0), y2 + (i * 64.0), 10.0);
                x2 += .314f;//*************

                System.out.print(test2[i][j] + " ");
            }
            y2 += .314f;//************

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perlin noise is defined to be 0 at all grid locations (integer x, y, z). You can prove this to yourself by hand-simulating it in the code you linked. Since `x`, `y`, and `z` all become 0 when their floors are subtracted, the `grad()` values are all 0, so the `lerp()` values are all 0.

There are several ways to get the noise you want. First, if you use a non-integer value of `z`, then you should get random values of noise. However, since your grid spacing of 64 is much larger than the noise basis, this will look like static, not Perlin noise. A better approach would be to scale up the noise by doing something like `noise(j/4., i/4., z)`. Sampling 4 points across each noise cell will allow some of the smoothness of the noise to be seen.

Note also that your noise implementation is designed to repeat with tiles of size 256 in each direction (see the first line of `noise()`. This is why you get repeating values every 4 in your array.

Comment: I tried everything you said. I made z be a non int value and got the same results. I also tried scaling the noise as you suggested by doing noise(j/4, i/4, z) and got the same results as well. Any other suggestions? Also, do you mean a tile of size 256x256 or an array holding 256 tiles?

Comment: The point I was trying to make in the last paragraph is that the noise function repeats every 256 (in x, y, and z). So, the value at (1, 3) is the same as at (257, 259) or (1, 769) or generally (x + 256n, y + 256m). Since 1024 and 768 are multiple of 256, of course the second array matches the first.

Comment: I'll check it out when I get home. I'm a FBM function anyways, I was just using this one for testing. I did get it to work last night by making a few changes, but I don't think it's ideal.